# Collection element of type ‘SEL' is not an Objective-C object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying a give a NSMutableArray value 'SEL', and XCode is giving me this error. My code:

```
SEL camera=@selector(p_userAlbum);
NSMutableArray *sels=@[camera].mutableCopy;
```

if there is a way to put a SEL in an Array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to make it with `NSStringFromSelector` and `NSSelectorFromString`

```
//Save
SEL camera=@selector(p_userAlbum);
NSString * selName = NSStringFromSelector(camera);
NSMutableArray *sels=@[selName].mutableCopy;

//Get
NSString * name = sels[0];
SEL mySel = NSSelectorFromString(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

its kind of self explanatory, ‘SEL' is not an objective-C object and NSArrays can only hold objective-c objects. but what you could do instead is use a block that can call your function (or just the actual code), since blocks are objective-c objects, and insert those into your array.

for example:

```
typedef void (^blockType)();

blockType blockName = ^(){
    //execute code or your function
};

NSArray *array = @[blockName];

blockType block = array[0]; //get the block out of the array later

block(); //run the block which will run your function or code
```